# Passing array of strings to a GraphQL query, convers to integers when embedded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, template-literals

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass an array of strings and embed it into a query (using React, GraphQL). The problem is it accepts the parameter as an array of strings, but converts it to a string when I embed it.

Let's say I have this function that makes a call to get some data. (I hardcoded the argument for now but it will be a variable as soon as I figure this out).

// here I'm calling the function

```
 const query = getData.generate(["123", "456"]);
        return GraphqlClient.query(query)
        .then((e) => {
            return e.data.oneAppProviders;
        }) .......
```

// and here is the query with the embedded parameter. (Backend expects an array of strings.)

```
export default {
generate(id) {
// console.log(id)        // output: ["123", "456"]
    return { query : gql`{
        oneAppProviders(id: ${id}) {
            id
            firstName
         }
    }
}}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
GraphQLError {message: "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int "456""
```

I guess, when I embed it, it converts it to integers... 
If my array is ["123"], I get the following error:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Expected type [String], found 123.
```

I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this helps someone:

```
export const UserFlagsQuery = gql`
  query($flags: [String!]!) {
    user {
      flags(where: { AND: [{ name_in: $flags }, { enabled: true }] }) {
        name
        enabled
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Use this query in a React `Query` component like this:

```
<Query
  query={UserFlagsQuery}
  variables={{
    flags: ["flag1", "flag2", "..."],
  }}
>
```

Thanks to @David Maze answer.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule you should avoid embedding data into query language strings like this.  (What if the `id` variable is actually a string containing parentheses and curly braces?  https://xkcd.com/327 is a more famous, if fictional, example of the potential problems you're facing.)

GraphQL supports top-level query parameters and you should use those here.  If you make your query like

```
query Providers($ids: [ID!]!) {
    oneAppProviders(id: $ids) {
        id
        firstName
     }
}
```

most query libraries have a way to pass in additional parameters; so in your case that might look like

```
const query = gql`...`;
const variables = { ids: ids };
GraphqlClient.query(query, variables).then(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to your problem is as follows:

```
let myarray = ["string1", "string2", "String3"];
let dataToSend = myarray.toString();
let gql`
{
   passArray(data:${dataToSend}){
   }
}`;
```